# Upgrade Flink 1.10 to Flink 1.11 (Log4j on kubernetes deployment)

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, apache-flink

After upgrade Flink 1.10 to Flink 1.11, the log4j configuration is no longer working.

my previous configuration was using a library with an adapter that requires log4j 1.x and is no longer compatible with Flink 1.11

according to the new configuration, the  flink-conf.yaml should look like this

```
log4j-console.properties: |+
    # This affects logging for both user code and Flink
    rootLogger.level = INFO
    rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender
    rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFileAppender

    # Uncomment this if you want to _only_ change Flink's logging
    #logger.flink.name = org.apache.flink
    #logger.flink.level = INFO
```

my current configuration using log4j1 looks something similar to this

```
log4j-console.properties: |+
         log4j.rootLogger=INFO,myappender,console
         log4j.appender.myappender=com.company.log4j.MyAppender
         log4j.appender.myappender.endpoints=http://
```

is there a way to tell Flink 1.11 to use log4j1 in the flink-conf.yaml file?

Comment: The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/logging.html#compatibility-with-log4j1) indicates that "Flink ships with the Log4j API bridge, allowing existing applications that work against Log4j1 classes to continue working." Perhaps you don't have to revert back to log4j1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `flink-conf.yaml` does not contain `log4j-console.properties` section and this is a separate file. What you have specified I suppose is a part of `flink-configuration-configmap.yaml` cluster resource definition.

According to the flink [Configuring Log4j1 Section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/logging.html#configuring-log4j1), in order to use log4j1, you need to:

- remove the `log4j-core`, `log4j-slf4j-impl` and `log4j-1.2-api` jars from the lib directory,
- add the `log4j`, `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j-to-slf4j` jars to the lib directory,

Comment: My Kubernetes config follows this configuration, using the docker image from docker. 
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html#common-cluster-resource-definitions.

Comment: Yes, I see. However, looking into dockerfile, https://github.com/apache/flink-docker/blob/master/1.11/scala_2.11-java8-debian/Dockerfile, it is based on flink-1.11.1-bin-scala_2.11.tgz, which includes log4j-core, log4j-slf4j-impl and log4j-1.2-api jars in lib folder. So, to make log4j1 work in your deployment, you need to change your flink docker image with the requirements above - remove some libs and replace with others.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the Flink-1.10.2 to Flink-1.11.3 I came across the same issue in the `Kubernetes` and `DCOS(Mesos)` Flink cluster. Then to cross-verify I downloaded the Flink's binaries `flink-1.11.3-bin-scala_2.12.tgz` in local and tested the loggers and found it working without any change.

**Flink 1.11 switched from Log4j1 to Log4j2**

- Then I have followed the steps mentioned in [Flink's official documents](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/monitoring/logging.html#configuring-log4j1) to use Flink with Log4j1.

  1. Remove the `log4j-core`, `log4j-slf4j-impl` and `log4j-1.2-api` jars from the `Flink's lib` directory.
  2. Add the `log4j`, `slf4j-log4j12`, and `log4j-to-slf4j` jars to the `Flink's lib` directory.
- Restarted the `Kubernetes` and `DCOS(Mesos)` Flink cluster and verified the loggers and found it working.